# How can I render different component using onClick() function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, buttonclick, conditional-rendering

I am new to React and creating a Tic-Tac-Toe game. I want to create a starting page with three options :

1. Start
2. Rules
3. Exit

On clicking the start button I want to render the  component which consists of the original game. On clicking rules I want to render a page showing rules. I have created seperate components for the three buttons and also the game itself.

[Screenshot-Start Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Hh0.jpg)

[Screenshot-Main Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGT3n.jpg)

[My Tic-Tac-Toe Repo](https://github.com/ayushman-sinha/tic-tac-toe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect to a new page containing one of your component you can use react router :
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

and use your button as a Link or use the useHistory hook in your onClick function

If you just want to render a component on the current page when you click on a button you can simply use a condition with a state like so :

```
...
const [isStart, setIsStart] = useState(false)

...
{isStart ? <Start> : <Button onClick={() => setIsStart(true)}>Start</Button>}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing my query. This seems to work but  what I want is that whenever I click the start button I want the start button to disappear and the required component be rendered on the screen.

Comment: Alright I made some edits, tell me if it suits you

Comment: Thank you.. I used if-else and got it to work..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `React Router` which is responsible for showing different components on different url paths, eg.:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import LandingPage from './landing-page/LandingPage';
import Details from './details/Details';

const Router = () => {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={`/`} exact render={() => <LandingPage />} />
                <Route path={`/details`} exact render={() => <Details />} />
            </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Router;
```

and then just redirects to those paths on click:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push('/results');
}

return (
<Button onClick={handleClick}>Results</Button>
);
```